# PHP & SQL: update record issue

Tags: php, mysql

Having some difficulty pinpointing exactly what is wrong with this block of code. I am expecting it to run through a loop a set number of times and update some rows in the table tbl_games with some values received from the form.

I have tried running the code in phpMyAdmin without variables, which works fine (updates specified row). I assume the problem is something to do with the string in $insert_q.

gamecount will always be an int<30, game_ID will be a unique primary key integer value in tbl_games.

A little background: this code is part of a bigger project - which is centered around football games. An admin adds games to tbl_games (coded and finished), this current file now displays games to the admin which are unplayed (scores for team1 and team2 are NULL) and gives them a space to input scores for each team. This code takes those 2 scores, and the game_ID and updates each row.

It's having no effect on the DB rows though. Please point me in the right direction.

```
<?php
    $lim=$_SESSION['gamecount'];
    for ($i=1; $i<$lim; $i++) {
        $game_ID = ${"_SESSION['game".$i."_ID']"};
        $score_team_1 = ${"_REQUEST['".$i."_team1-score']"};
        $score_team_2 = ${"_REQUEST['game".$i."_team2-score']"};
        $insert_q = "UPDATE tbl_games SET team1_score = '$score_team_1', team2_score = '$score_team_2' WHERE game_ID = '$game_ID';";
        mysql_query($insert_q);
    }
    session_destroy();
?>
```

Comment: You are missing an underscore on your `$_POST` -> `$game_ID = ${"_POST['game".$i."_ID']"};`

Comment: Also, it looks like you are missing `game` in `$score_team_1` -> `$score_team_1 = ${"_REQUEST['game".$i."_team1-score']"};`

Comment: Have you tried echoing out `$insert_q` to see what each query looks like to make sure it is correct/valid? Also, you could use `or die(mysql_error())` at the end of `mysql_query` to see if there are any errors. ie. `$insert_q = "UPDATE tbl_games ..."; echo $insert_q; mysql_query($insert_q) or die(mysql_error());`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with this line.

```
$game_ID = ${"POST['game".$i."_ID']"};
```

It should be something like this.

```
$game_ID = ${"_POST['game".$i."_ID']"}; or
$game_ID = $_POST['game'.$i.'_ID']; //much cleaner
```

Comment: Thanks for making that clearer to me. That's not resolved the issue though. The code responsible for setting the $_SESSION for game_ID is this:
`while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
$_SESSION['game'.$i.'_ID'] = $row['game_ID'];
$_SESSION['gamecount'] = $i;
$i++;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of the mysql reporting. Get it to output any errors, and affected rows. While you may think affected rows will be none, it might not be (always good to check when debugging just so you check everything).

Does your PHP error log have any warnings or other notices that might point to your query being an issue etc?

What is the value you're updating (echo out the var/session) and what is the DB value (look at it in phpmyadmin or mysql command line).
Could be there's nothing to update.